# How to avoid sharp jumps between speeds in css animation

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I need to create infinite animation that will start with fast rotation ( e.g. 1 second) then gradually slow down (within another e.g. 1 second) and then continue on the very slow speed (for the remaining e.g. 8 seconds). The problem is - rotation speed changes with very sharp jumps - on 10% and 20%.

Can I control transition between animation speeds? I tried to override speed jump by adding more percentages but it just gives second jump after 20% when speed changes.

```css
html {
height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bar {
  background: cyan;
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
}

.bar {
  animation: rotation 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: rotate(1600deg);
  }
  11% {
    transform: rotate(1620deg);
  }
  12% {
    transform: rotate(1640deg);
  }
  13% {
    transform: rotate(1660deg);
  }
  14% {
    transform: rotate(1680deg);
  }
  15% {
    transform: rotate(1700deg);
  }
  16% {
    transform: rotate(1720deg);
  }
  17% {
    transform: rotate(1740deg);
  }
  18% {
    transform: rotate(1760deg);
  }
  19% {
    transform: rotate(1800deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: rotate(1820deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(2160deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bar"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [multiple animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation): one for the initial spin with deceleration (take a look at the [easing functions](https://easings.net/). In this case I'm using `ease-out` which mimics basic deceleration) and a second (delayed to run after the first finishes) to be linear. You'll have to play around with the values of degrees and duration to match the speed of rotation from the first animation with the linear speed of the second, otherwise you'll see the speed jump quickly (your problem in the first place). Here's an example:

```css
html {
height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bar {
  background: cyan;
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
}

.bar {
  animation: rotationDecelerate 2s ease-out, rotationLinear 2s linear 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes rotationDecelerate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(2160deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotationLinear {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bar"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of fiddling with the numbers.

I removed all the intermediate transformations between 10 and 20%. The animation calculates the position of the element based on timing functions and the sort between the two points.

The reason why you were getting a big jump is that you were trying to control every intermediate step between 10 and 20 but the animation had to be at a certain point at 20%. Let the browser control everything between 10 and 20% since you want a smooth slowdown. The timing function takes into account where you started and where you want to end, so it tries to smooth everything out for you. The more defined every percentage point is, the more stilted the animation will be.

I also played around with the values a little bit. You can put them back how you want them, but I just wanted to see how it would affect the animation if the first sec was 5 rotations, then the next second was 1 rotation, and then last 80% was one rotation. It just seemed proportional to me, and the animation looked smoother. But, I recommend playing with the degrees until you get what you want.

```css
html {
height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bar {
  background: cyan;
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
}

.bar {
  animation: rotation 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: rotate(1800deg);
  }
  
  20% {
    transform: rotate(2160deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(2520deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bar"></div>
```